# How do I exclude a directory when searching for the directories that take up the most space?

Tags: directory, ls, disk-usage, rm

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.  I want to figure out what directories are taking up the most space, so I'm running this command

```
sudo du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 100
```

The problem is, most of the directories returned belong to a separate partition,

```
1048580 /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/postgresql/9.5/main/base/16419/57411.6
```

How do I exclude the `/mnt/volume-nyc1-01/` partition from my listing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man du` (note: this applies to GNU `du`, which should be applicable in your case):

```
--exclude=PATTERN
       exclude files that match PATTERN
```

so for example

```
sudo du -a --exclude='/mnt/volume-nyc1-01/*' / | sort -n -r | head -n 100
```

However in this case a better option might be to use the

```
   -x, --one-file-system
          skip directories on different file systems
```

option e.g.

```
sudo du -ax / | sort -n -r | head -n 100
```

(the other `sudo` commands in your pipeline shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: There's also `ncdu`, which takes the same exclude options as `du`, which gives a browse-able overview of disk usage.